# Rails Multiple checkboxes with associated Text fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, active-form

I'm trying to create a Product form that has multiple sizes and prices for each of those sizes.

They way I have it modelled is a has_many :through relationship.
The associative table contains an extra field for price such that it will now hold the product_id, size_id, and price.

I'm not sure how I should go about creating my form or how Rails expects this to look. Any help would be much appreciated.

My Product is Cake :)

```
class Cake < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cake_type

  has_many :cake_details
  has_many :sizes, through: :cake_details
end
```

Size model

```
class Size < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cake_details
  has_many :cakes, through: :cake_details
end
```

CakeDetail model
class CakeDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cake
  belongs_to :size
end

my migration

```
class CreateCakeDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :cake_details do |t|
      t.references :cake, foreign_key: true
      t.references :size, foreign_key: true
      t.decimal :price, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The only thing I'm stuck on is associating the form with the model.
i.e. for every size I want to have a text box with price associated with it.

This is currently how I'm approaching it but I have no idea how rails expects the id's of the text box to look or how I should structure this.

This is currently what I'm experimenting with in my form

```
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:cake, :size_ids, Size.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= b.label %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= b.check_box %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= form.text_field :cake_detail, id: b.label %>
      </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you define your business logic is normal

```
- A product has multiple sizes
- Each size has a price
```

The only thing I believe that it leads you to the problem is you are trying to **create everything at the same time**. Even Rails has `nested_attributes` which might solve your problem, but let's think once again.
Generally, `Size` records are fixed and was created beforehand. So that you don't have to create it at the same time with creating a `Product`.
Once you deal with this idea, your problem becomes much easier:

- You had a list of `Size`: M, L, XL, XXL ... that was created beforehand
  ( You may create them via `db/seeds.rb` )
- You want to create `Product` along `ProductDetail` with prices,
  and link the `ProductDetail` with `Size`

Now you can use Rails's `nested_attributes` for the relation `Product -> ProductDetail`

Your model

```
# app/models/cake.rb
class Cake < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cake_type

  has_many :cake_details
  has_many :sizes, through: :cake_details

  attr_accessor :is_enable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cake_details, reject_if: :is_not_good_detail?

  private
  def is_not_good_detail?(attributed)
    return true if attributed[:is_enable].to_i != 1
    # Check if CakeDetail is good or not
  end
end
```

Your controller

```
# app/controllers/cakes_controller.rb
class CakesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @cake = Cake.new
    # Build `cake_details`, so that you can render them at view
    Size.each do |size|
      @cake.cake_details.build(size_id: size.id, price: 0)
    end
  end

  def create
    # Create your Cake + CakeDetail
  end

  private

  def cake_params
    # permit your params here
  end
end
```

Your view

```
# app/views/cakes/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @cake do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :cakes_detail do |field| %>
    <%= field.check_box :is_enable %>
    <%= field.hidden_field :size_id %>
    <%= field.text_field :price %>
  <% end>
<% end %>
```

My code is completely not tested, and you still have a lot of things to do, but it should be the right way to solve your problem, tho.
You can consider the checklist to make it done:

- Display name of size. Ex: XL, XXL
- Permit the right params
- Reject the invalid CakeDetail attribute set.
- Avoid duplicate of size for a product when updating

#### << Update >>>

Since the `check_box` only produces `0` and `1` value, so using it for `size_id` is incorrect. We can solve it by:

- add an `attr_accessor` (ex: `is_enable`) for `CakeDetail` and use it for the `check_box`
- `size_id` become a hidden field
- Reject attributes if `is_enable != 1`

You can found here a working example [yeuem1vannam/product-size](https://github.com/yeuem1vannam/product-size)

Comment: I'm trying it but so far not really working I'm still hacking at it to get it working. I'd prefer to do it your way as your creating the objects in the controller. Except each value in my checkbox is equal to 1. :/
I saw the following railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised but like I said I like the way the above is building the objects in the controller.

Comment: @jimgug I updated the answer and provide a working example. The railscast is good, but it solves a different problem rather than yours.

Comment: I tried the above project but it doesn't really solve the issue I'm having it seems. It doesn't persist the check box values when I try to edit the product and it doesn't list the other sizes again if I want to add them. I haven't had a chance to mess around with the above and don't have the time at the moment but I will come back to this when I can.

Comment: I just read your update- your comment about check_box has me thinking about how correct it is to have specific values in there now! I'm not too strong in web development best practices but more reading for me I guess!